# typed.js start typing on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, typed.js

i have got this code:

```
<h1 class="font" id="typed3" style="text-align: center; font-size: 400%; color: black;">About Us</h1>
<br>
<br>

<script>

  var typed2 = new Typed('#typed3', {
      strings: ['About Us'],
      typeSpeed: 400,
      

      backSpeed: 0,
      fadeOut: true,
    });
  </script>
```

for typed.js but I want it to start typing out when the user has scrolled to the text. is this possible?

Comment: Check out the [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) - you should be able to use it to detect when a certain div comes into the viewport

Comment: but how could i get my typed.js to happen on scroll though?

Comment: See the answer I just posted and let me know if it works for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with the typed.js library you mentioned specifically - but assuming the code you've shown works how you expect, you can run it when your `<h1>` comes into view by using an [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API):

Check out this fiddle to see the IntersectionObserver in action with your example: https://jsfiddle.net/Ollie1700/0q7on5d2/8/

IntersectionObserver behaviour isn't exactly trivial and on the face of it it seems like there are a lot of moving parts. But all we are doing here is the following:

1. Initialise a new IntersectionObserver with a callback that contains information about intersections
2. We instruct the IntersectionObserver to observe the element with ID "typed3". This means that when the "#typed3" element comes into the viewport, the callback for the IntersectionObserver will be triggered
3. Within the callback, we are provided an array of entries (since the IntersectionObserver can observe more than one DOM element). In this case we create a loop but we could also just reference `entries[0]` if we wanted since we know there is only going to be one element
4. The IntersectionObserver API provides us with the `isIntersecting` flag which is `true` when the observed element is visible within the viewport. So we use an if statement with this flag that triggers your original typedjs code.
5. After triggering the typedjs code, we instruct the IntersectionObserver to stop observing (`unobserve`) our element, otherwise the code would be run every time the element comes into view. (Although this may be the behaviour you want, so experiment with omitting the `unobserve` call)

Let me know if this works out for you.

Comment: how do i link IntersectionObserver with my code? as nothing is happening so I'm assuming I need to link something?

Comment: Try and replace the contents of your `<script>` tag with the code I provided. Also make sure that the `Typed` script comes before the script, otherwise you might get errors about `Typed` being undefined.

Comment: @PhilipTrevor I was able to get it working on this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Ollie1700/0q7on5d2/8/ I have updated my answer with this since the code I provided had a few bugs

Comment: It works really well but how do I do it for this:

<h1 class="font" id="typed100" style="text-align: center; font-size: 400%; color: black;"></h1>

I cant do it? Please help!